# Load routes dynamically in express js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, custom-routes

I am building a blog like app, and posts can be created in the admin dashboard and the public user can visit a published post via the category and permalink.

I have having issues thinking about how to register the routes in my express app.

The solution I have in mind is to fetch all posts and use a for loop to register the routes on app init. The controller is pretty simple, just render the same template.

```
posts.forEach((post)=> {
    app.get(':' + post.category + '/:' + post.slug, renderPostGenericController);
})
```

Will like to vet this solution and know if there is any other better way to do this.

Answer (score 3):

You can register one route:

```
app.get('/post/:category/:slug', (req, res) {
    // req.params.category
    // req.params.slug
    ...
});
```

This way, in your route handler you'll have access to both parameters. Now you can fetch the correct post from the DB (or wherever) with the provided category and slug.

Comment: Was thinking of a way to do it without having a base path. My desired url should be `www.example.com/javascript/introduction-to-javascscript` and not `www.example.com/post/javascript/introduction-to-javascript` Any thought?